# Dropbox chooser does not return to UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using the dropbox chooser for iOS in my app. Right now, I am not downloading anything, just letting the user click on file in the chooser (just calling NSLog to output some stuff to console for now). Trouble is, I expected that after the file has been chosen in the chooser, I expected control would return to my calling     UIViewController     but it does not. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I should specify that the calling view controller is the 3rd view controller (the 1st view controller being the one that show the first view when my app is started). Control actually returns to my first view controller, instead of what should have been the top view controller in the stack.

Comment: What code are you using to dismiss the "Dropbox chooser" view?

Comment: The chooser box is automatically dismissed once a file is chosen.